# Unexpected Token U Posting To Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I keep getting an unexpected token u when using ajax to post data to express. I checked the variables to make sure they weren't undefined so I'm unsure where I've gone wrong.

*functions.js*

```
$('#saveClause').click(function () {
    var username = document.getElementById('postUserName').innerText;
    var clauseTitle = document.getElementById('modalTitle').innerText;
    var clauseDescription = document.getElementById('modalDescription').innerText;
    var clauseText = document.getElementById('modalText').innerText;

    //alert(username + " " + clauseTitle + " " + clauseDescription + " " + clauseText);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/classes/updateAssignment",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            username: username,
            title: clauseTitle,
            description: clauseDescription,
            text: clauseText
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache:false,
        timeout: 5000,
        complete: function() {
          console.log("Process Complete");  
        }, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Process Success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Process Error");
        },

    });
})
```

*classes.js route*

```
router.post('/updateAssignment', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username)
    console.log(req.body.title);
    console.log(req.body.description);
    console.log(req.body.text);
    res.contentType('json');
    res.send({
        some: JSON.stringify({
            response: 'json'
        })
    });


});
```